# WHERE IN SELECT replace on join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT
    count(*) as count
FROM
    USERS.Names p1
WHERE
    p1.rowid IN (
            SELECT p2.rowid
            FROM USERS.Names p2
            WHERE
                p2.Id = p1.Id AND p2.status = p1.Status
                AND p2.DateTo = (SELECT max(p3.dateTo)
                                FROM USERS.Names p3
                                WHERE p3.entityid = p1.Id
                                        AND p3.status = p1.Status
                                        AND p3.Code = p2.Code)
  )
  AND p1.Status = 1
  AND p1.Id >= 12
  AND p1.Id < 31308;
```

Сan I remove the nested `SELECT`s and replace them with the `JOIN`s? This request is working for a long time

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to do really help.

Comment: Formally, the  answer to your question is **YES**, but then I would be wandering on around this: **_If it works, why to change it?_**

Comment: If you can update your question with sample data and expected output, there are alternatives for nested SQL, are you facing any performance issue?

Comment: @FDavidov The hexagonal wheel on my bicyle works, but I'm changing it as soon as I can.

Comment: @Strawberry my boldface-italics question was meant to say the same :-).

Comment: @FDavidov OK. It comes across as the exact opposite.

Comment: @Strawberry, I was about to write that you meant "change if because it is ugly". Still, even it ugly, if it works and does not create issues (e.g. performance), why to change it?

Comment: @FDavidov My hexagonal wheel is a delight to behold. But it's quite uncomfortable, and I think a round wheel might perform better.

Comment: @FDavidov, This query work long time

Comment: @All_Safe . . . Ask another question about how to speed up the processing for this query.  Don't assume a particular answer, if your goal is to improve performance.

Comment: @All_Safe, you wrote "_This request is working for a long time_", meaning, it is part of the system since long ago and is working. If you meant **_this query takes long time to complete_**, then be more clear with your wording.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    count(*) as count
FROM
    USERS.Names p1
INNER JOIN
    SELECT (
        MAX(dateto) MaxDateto
    FROM USERS.Names) p2
        ON p1.dateto = p2.MaxDateto
WHERE
    p1.Status = 1
    AND p1.Id >= 12
    AND p1.Id < 31308;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following may be you're looking for :

```
SELECT count(1) count
  FROM Names p3 
            JOIN 
                (
                 SELECT max(p1.dateTo) dateTo_max
                   FROM Names p1 JOIN Names p2 
                     ON ( p2.entityid = p1.Id )  
                  WHERE p1.dateTo = p2.dateto
                    AND p1.Status = 1
                    AND p1.Id between 12 AND 31307) p4 
                     ON ( p3.dateto = p4.dateTo_max );
```